# How to deploy applications created with Mono to mobile devices

Tags: c#, mobile, mono

Is it possible to deploy .NET applications targeted for Mono framework on mobile devices? What do I need to take into consideration when creating such applications?

Comment: Maybe a little more information would be helpfull, the question is very vague. Do you have any specific mobile devices you would like to install your application on?

Comment: This really isn't a SO question, look at the mono documentation for implementation details.

Comment: yes the mobile may be nokia51300 then ?

Answer (score 0):

There are mono frameworks for iPhone/iPad and Android (commercial).

On Android it allows you to write the business logik in C# and add the UI layer via XML configuration files (like in the original develpment style).

It works!

But easy? No!

Answer (score 0):

The primary thing you need to take into account is that you need to split your application into the UI portions and the backend. You should be able to share the backend code between devices but you will likely be re-authoring the UI portions for each platform that you target.

Another thing to keep in mind is that some devices need to compile down to native code so you may not be able to use features like Reflection.

Which tech to use for the UI depends on the platform:

For iOS devices (iPhone and iPad) you should use [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)

For Android devices you should use [MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/)

For Windows Phone 7 you will be using Silverlight or XNA ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))

For Nokia devices (prior to WP7) you can use [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp)

That pretty much covers it unless I really misunderstand your question.